# Objective c and apex webservice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, soap, apex-code

I need to send an apex web service some data. Then name of the webservice is "UpdateData" and the name of the method is "update" and it takes these params:

```
id = String 
type = String
BinaryObject = Blob / Base64 Encoded value
BinaryObjectType = String
```

I was also given a WSDL file.

I have no idea how to send this data to the web service, can someone point me in the correct direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good soap/wsdl stack for iOS. You might want to look at the [force.com iOS toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS), it contains some code to help call custom apex web services.